# How do I update new collection values?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need a way to update a collection that I am getting from the html form.

I have an array of

```
Product ids: 
array:3 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]

Product quantity: 
array:3 [
  0 => "15"
  1 => "5"
  2 => "7"
]

Product Price:

array:3 [
  0 => "12.00"
  1 => "2.50"
  2 => "4.00"
]
```

I am storing/saving the values to the database with something like this:

```
$product_ids = $request->get('product_ids');
$product_prices = $request->get('product_prices');
$product_quantities = $request->get('product_quantities');
$product_descriptions = $request->get('product_descriptions');

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($product_ids); $i++) {

    $item = new Order_item;

    $item->order_id = $order->id;
    $item->product_id = $product_ids[$i];
    $item->unit_price = $product_prices[$i];
    $item->description = $product_descriptions[$i];

    $item->quantity = $product_quantities[$i];

    $item->save();
}
```

Comment: isn't it that laravel has some sort of update or create operation on their eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the record based on id and then save the changed data:

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

From https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates

If you're using order_id as the key, then use a where() statement with first():

```
$order = App\Order_item::where('order_id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I just edited my question. For a single value your answer is correct. But I need a way to update the values from an array.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with something like this:

```
        $product_ids = $request->get('product_ids');
        $product_prices = $request->get('product_prices');
        $product_quantities = $request->get('product_quantities');
        $product_descriptions = $request->get('product_descriptions');
```

Fetched the values using `$request->get`.

And updated the values using a for loop.

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($product_ids); $i++) {
            Order_item::where('order_id', $id)
                ->where('product_id', $i + 1)->update(
                    [   'quantity' => $product_quantities[$i],
                        'unit_price' =>  $product_prices[$i],
                        'description' => $product_descriptions[$i],
                    ]);
```